# Will shiny work online without shiny-server?

Tags: r, iframe, server, shiny

I need to integrate a shiny application to some existing php/html code. And I've seen that its possible to run the app by typing :

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('path_to_shiny', port=9999)"
```

So I've plan to run this script on the server and put a iframe which redirect to this. May it work ?

Comment: I would be interested in the outcome, I'm guessing that your running `R` is supposed to act as a server but how you are going to handle multiple user instances? For a simple app it appears to be possible to run it get the URL `http://127.0.0.1:6990` and access the URL through multiple browser passing different instructions (so I'm guessing that `shiny::runApp` maintains necessary multiple instances of the app).

Answer (score 1):

You can let the Shiny server run on a different port than the webserver (default 80). For example, see the [default configuration](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#default-configuration) of shiny server, which lets shiny run on port 3838. This is better than running an R process with the shiny package inside of it, because you get startup scripts for shiny server that handle all sorts of cases that you would have to handle manually otherwise (e.g., restarting the R process when the server reboots, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add `host` argument with `'0.0.0.0'` in your code as well like below,

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('path_to_shiny', host='0.0.0.0', port=9999)"
```

And, you also need to be sure that that server is not using port 9999, for example, if web server uses port 80 (i.e. yoururl.com), you may need to change to some port something like yoururl.com:8080, in case of any conflict. So basically you can run two different apps like this.